# Как реализовать наследование модели ActiveRecord?

Tags: наследование, activerecord, ruby-on-rails

К примеру есть `BaseModel` и `SomeModel<BaseModel`

```
BaseModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  def method1
  end
  def metho22
  end
end

SomeModel < BaseModel
  def somemethod
  end
end
```

У BaseModel так же есть поля field1, field2, хранящиеся в бд, созданные миграцией.
Таким образом SomeModel будет так же иметь методы BaseModel и поля field1, field2.
Что делать если есть необходимость в других полях в модели SomeModel? Можно ли реализовать хранение полей относящихся к SomeModel в другой таблице бд?

Comment: пожалуйста, не используйте STI.

Answer (score 1):

Можешь воспользоваться STI(Single Table Inheritance)

что это - [STI — одна таблица и много моделей](http://habrahabr.ru/post/79630/)

как применить - http://thibaultdenizet.com/tutorial/single-table-inheritance-with-rails-4-part-1/

если я правильно поняла суть вопроса)